# Perl regular expression match tags that may not be there

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I am trying to construct a Perl regular expression that will match strings like this:

```
no tags
beginning<tag>this is tag</tag>rest of line
<tag1>this is tag1</tag1>
<tag1>this is tag1</tag1>rest of line
```

I want to use grouping to extract the tags and what's in between them.

I tried to use this:

```
$a="beginning<tag>this is tag</tag>rest of line";

print "a=$a\n\n";

($x0, $x1, $x2, $x3, $x4, $x5) = ($a =~ /(.*?)(<tag>)(.*)(<\/tag>)(.*)/);

print "x0=$x0\n";
print "x1=$x1\n";
print "x2=$x2\n";
print "x3=$x3\n";
print "x4=$x4\n";


a=beginning<tag>this is tag</tag>rest of line

x0=beginning
x1=<tag>
x2=this is tag
x3=</tag>
x4=rest of line
```

Which does what I want, but if this is source string:

```
a=there are no tags

x0=
x1=
x2=
x3=
x4=
```

Nothing matches.

Comment: [`<(\w+)>(.*?)</\1>`](http://regex101.com/r/aQ7zU3)

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: I should have made that clear in the post - I can't use a proper parsing library, as the machines this has to run on can't be easily upgraded with new CPAN modules.

Comment: You can always copy/paste the module's code directly into your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for (see [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lJ8lA2)):

```
(?m)(.*?)(?:$|(<[^>]*>)([^<]*)(</[^>]*>)(.*))
```

**How does this work?**

1. The `(?m)` multi-line modifier at the top ensures that the `$` can match the end of every line since you seem to be working in a file.
2. The first capture group `(.*?)` is followed by an alternation: either the `$` end of the line, which allows you to capture the string when there is no tag; `|` OR your tag and optional tail.

Comment: That does it - I didn't know about the (?:) alternation operator.

Comment: @user1279887 Glad to hear it works for you! The `|` is the alternation operator, the `(?: something)` is just a non-capturing group so that we don't mess up your group numbers by adding capturing parentheses. :)

Comment: Instead of `(?:$|...)`, it might be clearer to use `(?:...)?`.

Comment: @Miller That would create a regex where every component is optional, leading to all kinds of weirdness. See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/oM2cY3) for instance. That was probably part of the original problem he couldn't solve and that's why I offered that `$` solution. :)

Comment: @zx81 There is no functional difference between the regex that you provided and the one that I did.  The 4 capture groups in your regex are also *"optional"*.  So if there is *"wierdness"* to occur, they will occur in both.

Comment: @Miller I don't want to argue in a vacuum... Actually I don't like arguing at all. :) I showed a [working demo](http://regex101.com/r/lJ8lA2) and [failing demo](http://regex101.com/r/oM2cY3). Can you please give me a demo that replicates the result of my working demo so I can understand what you are talking about? I may be missing something subtle in your point.

Comment: @zx81 will be idling in a [`chat room`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54476/room-for-miller-and-zx81) if you'd like to figure out where/if we're misunderstanding each other.

Comment: Scratch that.  I agree with your regex in the context of `/g`.  Please disregard my comments :)

Comment: @user1279887 your comment is not complete. :)

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain why the (?:$|...) has to be coded that way? If I move switch the matching of the end line part with the main tag matching it no longer works. I thought alternation would like either way, e.g a|b == b|a? I'm just trying to understand how you came up with this - it doesn't seem very intuitive.

Comment: @user1279887 Like many things in regex there are several ways to do it, it just came out like that. The reason for the alternation that way is that the first group used a lazy `.*?`... So if the second part was made optional, it would match a lot of single characters. Another way to go (you may prefer this) is to grab the first part with `[^<]*` and get rid of the alternation: `([^<\r\n]*)(?:(<[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<\/[^>]*>)(.*))?` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uM9cS3) Since you're on multiple lines we also include `\r\n` in the negated class. Always compromises, input dictates.  :)